# Adding a calculated column x from two values of another column y in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I would like to transform the column 'x' so that xn=yn-yn+1, n being the index.

```
# importing the dataframe:
import pandas as pd

​data = pd.read_csv('data_xy.csv')
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

# printing the dataframe:
data
    x   y
0   2   15
1   3   13
2   4   10
3   1   6
4   3   5
5   0   2
```

I tried this way, but it does not work:

```
# Try of redefining 'x' as xn = yn - yn1:
data['x'] = data['y'] - data[1:, 'y']

# Error message:
InvalidIndexError: (slice(1, None, None), 'y')
```

I also thought about the .iloc() method, but I can't figure how exactly to use it for my purpose

I have not been able to find a previous question similar to mine, although it must have already been asked.

Comment: use .shift(1) on the y column see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Comment: ```data['x'] = data['y'].diff()```

Comment: Both @darthbaba & dramarama answers calculate xn=yn-yn-1 instead of xn=yn-yn+1

Comment: @ErikFubel you are right,  update: ```data['x'] = data['y'].diff(-1)```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`Series.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html). With it, you can shift the values of column y by n rows.

```py
In [1]: data['x'] = data['y'] - data['y'].shift(-1)
   ...: data

Out[1]: 
     x   y
0  2.0  15
1  3.0  13
2  4.0  10
3  1.0   6
4  3.0   5
5  NaN   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff`:

```
data['x'] = data['y'].diff(-1).fillna(0)
print(data)

# Output
     x   y
0  2.0  15
1  3.0  13
2  4.0  10
3  1.0   6
4  3.0   5
5  0.0   2
```